# WSS 3.0 managing multiple versions of the same document in a parallel development environment

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0

We are using WSS 3.0 at work to manage design documents for our systems.  We work in a parallel environment which means we usually have a production copy of a document (e.g Doc A) plus also two or more versions of that document that will be worked on by independent project teams (Doc A (proj 1) & Doc A (proj 2)), we have in the past achieved this by keeping the documents in seperate site collections, however this is very messy and over time has become extremely hard to keep track of the latest versions.

What I am trying to achieve is to store all versions of Doc A in the same document library keeping the name the same but distinguish the different versions of the document using meta-data fields so that users will be able to view the production version of the document while proj 1 and proj 2 can work on their documents seperately.  Each individual version of the document must also be searchable using the WSS search.

E.g  Name       Project Name
     Doc A      Production
     Doc A      Proj 1
     Doc A      Proj 2

I have thought about simply using version control in the library to maintain the different versions of the document and allow the users to simply go to version history to choose which document they want to view or work on.  The issue with this approach is that I can not get the seperate version of the document to show up in the search results.

I am stuck with WSS 3.0 for at least another 12 months, so my solution has to be WSS 3.0 based.

Has anyone had experience trying to implement something similar and if so what was the solution that you used?  I can't imagine that I am the only one trying to cater for a paraelle development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  Renaming Document is the solution (Post-fixing something to make distinct document name).

Long Answer: I got chance to migrate huge document base from oracle portal to MOSS 2007 and I spent time to find out the solution. Finally I ended up post-fixing versions manually/programmatically in the event handler.

Regards,

Azher

Comment: Thanks Azher, that would have been the easier way around this, however this is not possible as they want to keep the document names the same for all versions of it because once a project is completed, it will replace the production version as the new production. We have a central page with hyperlinks to each production document.  I did play around with the idea of adding meta data fields that will uniquely identify the documents, similar concept to document sets in 2010, however WSS 3 still looked for the document name as the unique identifier and asked to replace existing document on upload.

Comment: Required feature is not available OOB. When I shall be in this situation then I shall go for writing my own document lib that will not have document name as unique column and save the documents in database as BLOB.